# Computed table column with MAX value between rows containing a shared value

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE T2
( ID_T2 integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_T1 integer,                    <--- foreign key to T1(Table1)
  FK_DATE date,                     <--- foreign key to T1(Table1)
  T2_DATE date,                     <--- user input field
  T2_MAX_DIFF COMPUTED BY ( (SELECT DATEDIFF (day, MAX(T2_DATE), CURRENT_DATE) FROM T2 GROUP BY FK_T1) )
);
```

I want T2_MAX_DIFF to display the number of days since last input across all similar entries with a common FK_T1.

It does work, but if another FK_T1 values is added to the table, I'm getting an error about *"multiple rows in singleton select"*.

I'm assuming that I need some sort of `WHERE FK_T1 = FK_T1 of corresponding row`. Is it possible to add this? I'm using Firebird 3.0.7 with flamerobin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *"multiple rows in singleton select"* means that a query that should provide a single scalar value produced multiple rows. And that is not unexpected for a query with `GROUP BY FK_T1`, as it will produce a row per `FK_T1` value.

To fix this, you need to use a correlated sub-query by doing the following:

1. Alias the table in the subquery to disambiguate it from the table itself
2. Add a where clause, making sure to use the aliased table (e.g. `src`, and `src.FK_T1`), and explicitly reference the table itself for the other side of the comparison (e.g. `T2.FK_T1`)
3. (optional) remove the `GROUP BY` clause because it is not necessary given the `WHERE` clause. However, leaving the `GROUP BY` in place may uncover certain types of errors.

The resulting subquery then becomes:

```sql
(SELECT DATEDIFF (day, MAX(src.T2_DATE), CURRENT_DATE) 
 FROM T2 src 
 WHERE src.FK_T1 = T2.FK_T1 
 GROUP BY src.FK_T1)
```

Notice the alias `src` for the table referenced in the subquery, the use of `src.FK_T1` in the condition, and the explicit use of the table in `T2.FK_T1` to reference the column of the current row of the table itself. If you'd use `src.FK_T1 = FK_T1`, it would compare with the `FK_T1` column of `src` (as if you'd used `src.FK_T1 = src.FK_T2`), so that would always be true.

```sql
CREATE TABLE T2
( ID_T2 integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_T1 integer, 
  FK_DATE date,
  T2_DATE date,
  T2_MAX_DIFF COMPUTED BY ( (
    SELECT DATEDIFF (day, MAX(src.T2_DATE), CURRENT_DATE) 
    FROM T2 src 
    WHERE src.FK_T1 = T2.FK_T1 
    GROUP BY src.FK_T1) )
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to add the date from T1 into the datediff line, with COALESCE. Basically, I have one date in T1 and multiple dates in T2 (when was T1 updated). I'm interested in getting the last date.

`SELECT DATEDIFF (day, COALESCE (MAX(src.T2_DATE), T1_DATE), CURRENT_DATE)
FROM T2 src, T2, T1
WHERE src.FK_T1 = T2.FK_T1
GROUP BY src.FK_T1`

I'm receiving an error with the above; "Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)"

Comment: That is because the expresson as shown isn't valid because both `day` and `t1_date` aren't part of your `group by` (but adding them to the `group by` is not the solution!). You will need to restructure your query in a way that produces the desired result. I recommend asking a new question.