# Grouping issue in computed column to display days passed since last update, returns a "multiple row in singleton select" error

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

As a followup question to [Computed table column with MAX value between rows containing a shared value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478229/computed-table-column-with-max-value-between-rows-containing-a-shared-value) ,
Considering the following tables and values:

```
 T1ID   T1DATE            T2ID   FK_T1ID    T2DATE
  1     01/03/21            1        1        04/03/21
  2     05/03/21            2        1        05/03/21
  3     05/03/21            3        1        07/03/21
  4     null                4        2        07/03/21
```

Expected results in T1 table (assuming current date is 10.03.21):

```
 T1ID   T1DATE          DATEDIFF (computed column)
  1       01/03/21       3   (calculated from record 3 of T2, since it is most recent)
  2       05/03/21       3   (calculated from record 4 of T2, more recent than T1DATE)
  3       05/03/21       5   (calculated from T1DATE, since no rec in T2 where T1ID = FK_T1ID)
  4       null           null (null since neither T1DATE is available or rec with T1ID = FK_T1ID)
```

I want to write a computed column into T1 that calculates how many days have passed since the latest T2DATE, and if no T2 date is present, calculated from the T1DATE.

I tried using

```
alter table T1 add DATEDIFF computed by
((SELECT DATEDIFF (day, COALESCE(MAX(T2DATE), T1DATE), CURRENT_DATE) 
  FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1ID=FK_T1ID GROUP BY T1ID, T1DATE))
```

This does produce a valid query (when ran in libre base, directly through firebird) but when I open the T1 table in either libre base or flamerobin, I get an error "multiple rows in singleton select".
Before adding the T1DATE at the GROUP BY part, I was getting an aggregate error when running the query, although I don't understand why, because T1DATE corresponds to one T1ID.

I'm using firebird 3.0.7 with flamerobin and libre office 7.0.4.

I did manage to somehow solve this by different means, using 3 computed columns (one for DIFF(T1DATE), one for DIFF(MAX(T2DATE)) and a third for COALESCE between those two).
Initially this did not work, as libre base was giving the "multiple rows in singleton select", but as of writing this, this no longer happens and the dates are calculated as expected.

How can I fix the above computed column to avoid using 3 computed columns?

Comment: This essentially a duplicate from your previous question. The problem is that your current query produces more than 1 row, and the expression of the computed column must produce at most one row. Please show the expected result for the given sample data, so we can help you write the correct query.

Comment: I've edited the main post to add expected results in T1 and also removed the '.' in column names or replaced with '_'.
I just can't wrap my head around it. I've tried yesterday for hours.

Comment: Using of subqueries in calculated fields is a very bad idea. Don't do it.  
If you insist - use a view.